# Python, клиент-серверное приложение, не подключается

Tags: python-3.x, асинхронность, клиент-сервер

Почему-то в следующей элементарной программе соединение клиента с сервером происходит только со второго раза. И так каждый раз после перезапуска сервера. Может кто объяснить причину такого поведения и как решить эту проблему? Может дело в том, что asyncore используется только на стороне сервера? (Windows 7, Python 3) Заранее спасибо!
Клиент:
    import socket

```
sock = socket.socket()#создаем сокет
host = 'localhost'
port = 8081
tempr = port
sock.connect((host,port))
```

Сервер: 
    import asyncore
    import socket
    import time

```
class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

 def handle_read(self):
     data = self.recv(1024)

class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
  def __init__(self, host, port):
      asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
      self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      self.set_reuse_addr()
      self.bind((host, port))
      self.listen(2)

  def handle_accept(self):
      pair = self.accept()
      if pair is not None:
          sock, addr = pair
          print ('Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr))
          handler = EchoHandler(sock)

def main():
      host = 'localhost'
      port = 8081
      server = EchoServer(host, port)

      print ('Сервер %s запущен'% port)
      asyncore.loop()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
      main()
```

Comment: Я точно не помню как устроен asyncio, но что-то мне подсказывает, что вы зря handle_accept сами вызываете

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Убрал вызов - его я добавил от безыходности, до этого тоже не с первого раза подключалось (

Comment: На двух форумах уже спросил и везде тишина. Это неразрешимая проблема?

Comment: Код для сервера взят отсюда (в самом низу): https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html

Comment: не используйте asyncore. Для нового кода рекомендуется asyncio использовать.